# adding GLcontrol to visual studio toolbox

Tags: c#, winforms, opentk

maybe the question is simple but I'm using OpenTK with WinForms , the problem is I can't find GLcontrol in the toolbox , so I added it manually in Form1.Designer.cs , this is the code 
   #region Windows Form Designer generated code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        glcontrol1 = new OpenTK.GLControl();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // glControl1
        // 

        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.Controls.Add(glcontrol1);
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(584, 561);     
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
    OpenTK.GLControl glcontrol1;
```

the problem is when I open Form1 in design mode , It shows these messages 
"could not load type OpenTK.ToolkitOptions from assembly ..."
"the variable glcontrol1 is either undeclared or not assigned "
I'd like a way to add GLcontrol to toolbox , anyone knows how ?

Comment: this is the call stack in case needed :
at OpenTK.GLControl..ctor(GraphicsMode mode, Int32 major, Int32 minor, GraphicsContextFlags flags)
at OpenTK.GLControl..ctor()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check your project references, you need both `OpenTK.dll` and `OpenTK.GLControl.dll`.

Adding GLControl to the WinForms toolbox is covered under ["Building a Windows.Forms + GLControl based application"](http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/glcontrol) in the documentation.

> To begin with, create a Form on which you will place your GLControl. Right click in some empty space of the Toolbox, pick "Choose Items..." and browse for `OpenTK.GLControl.dll`. Make sure you can find the "GLControl" listed in the ".NET Framework Components", as in the image below.

[image: Adding GLControl to the Toolbox]

> Then you can add the GLControl to your form as any .NET control. A GLControl named glControl1 will be added to your Form.

Comment: thank you , now I have another problem , when I drag GLcontrol to the form , the same messages appear :
could not load type OpenTK.ToolkitOptions from assembly at OpenTK.GLControl..ctor(GraphicsMode mode, Int32 major, Int32 minor, GraphicsContextFlags flags) at OpenTK.GLControl..ctor()

Comment: someone told me maybe the problem in my OpenTK , so I installed it but the same problem appears ! , and the strange thing is that I opened my project in another computer and it worked , maybe it's my windows , though it used to work , I have Windows 8.1 x64 and the other computer's Windows 7 x86 I think .

Comment: It may be that you have more than one versions of OpenTK lying around and Visual Studio is getting confused. Navigate to OpenTK/Binaries/OpenTK/Release and run `Examples.exe`. Do the examples work? If they do, (a) copy-paste OpenTK.dll and OpenTK.GLControl.dll directly to your project, (b) remove the exist OpenTK references from your project, and (c) add the dlls you just copied as project references.